# Rotating a rectangle-shaped Polygon around it's center. (Java)

Tags: java, swing, matrix, rotation, polygon

I have this code to draw a rectangle (Polygon object), and then draw another rectangle which is the original one, rotated 90 degrees, using the rotation matrix.

```
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        Point p1,p2,p3,p4;
        p1 = new Point(50,50);
        p2 = new Point(200,50);
        p3 = new Point(200,100);
        p4 = new Point(50,100);

        int[] x = {(int) p1.getX(), (int) p2.getX(), (int)p3.getX(), (int) p4.getX()};
        int[] y = {(int) p1.getY(), (int) p2.getY(), (int)p3.getY(), (int) p4.getY()};

        Polygon poly = new Polygon(x, y, x.length);
        g2d.draw(poly);

        p1.setLocation(p1.getX() * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)) - p1.getY() * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90)),
                p1.getX() * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90)) + p1.getY() * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)));
        p2.setLocation(p2.getX() * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)) - p2.getY() * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90)),
                p2.getX() * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90)) + p2.getY() * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)));
        p3.setLocation(p3.getX() * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)) - p3.getY() * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90)),
                p3.getX() * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90)) + p3.getY() * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)));
        p4.setLocation(p4.getX() * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)) - p4.getY() * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90)),
                p4.getX() * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90)) + p4.getY() * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)));

        int[] x2 = {(int) p1.getX(), (int) p2.getX(), (int)p3.getX(), (int) p4.getX()};
        int[] y2 = {(int) p1.getY(), (int) p2.getY(), (int)p3.getY(), (int) p4.getY()};

        Polygon poly2 = new Polygon(x2, y2, x2.length);
        g2d.draw(poly2);

    }

}
```

Currently, the second rectangle doesn't show up. When I asked about this in a different question, someone answered that that's because it draws outside the screen.

I asked how to rotate the rectangle around it's center, so the new drawing will appear in the screen, and he answered but I didn't really understand how to implement what he said in the code (tried different things that didn't work).

Could you show me exactly in the code, how to rotate the rectangle around it's center?

(Of course this isn't actual rotating of an object. It's making a rotated-duplicate of an object).

Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you translate the Graphics to the rectangle center, then rotate it, then draw a rectangle using these new coordinates (and the un-rotate and un-translate the graphics)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you are trying to rotate around the rectangle's center, first you need to translate the rectangle to the **origin**, then apply the rotation and finally translate back. See the following code (adapted to your case) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16743716/2670792) in another post.

```
//TRANSLATE TO ORIGIN
double x1 = p1.getX() - center.x;
double y1 = p1.getY() - center.y;

//APPLY ROTATION
double temp_x1 = x1 * Math.cos(angle) - y1 * Math.sin(angle));
double temp_y1 = x1 * Math.sin(angle) + y1 * Math.cos(angle));

//TRANSLATE BACK
p1.setLocation(temp_x1 + center.x, temp_y1 + center.y);
```

You have to do this for each point. Also you will need to find the center of the rectangle `center.x` and `center.y`.

**Explanation**
When you directly apply the rotation, you are rotating it around the origin `(0,0)` (you can easily see this when you change the angle rotation in your code). If you want to rotate around the center of the rectangle, you have to follow the steps described above.

- **Translate the shape (rectangle) to origin**, this can be accomplished by substracting the center components to the point's components.
- **Apply rotation to the translated points** around the origin `(0,0)`.
- **Translate back each point to the original position**, by adding the center components (the ones you substracted in the first step).

**Edit 1:**

Let's say we have a Rectangle (Square) which vertex are:

```
p1: (2, 2)
p2: (3, 2)
p3: (3, 3)
p4: (2, 3)
```

For point `p2`:

**In first step:**

```
center: (2.5, 2.5)
x1 = 3 - 2.5 = 0.5
y1 = 2 - 2.5 = -0.5
```

Doing this for each point:

```
new_p1: (-0.5, -0.5)
new_p2: (0.5, -0.5)
new_p3: (0.5, 0.5)
new_p4: (-0.5, 0.5)
```

Then you apply the rotation...

**Edit 2:** I hope it gets clearer with this image, sorry if I'm bad with Paint.

[image: Explanation]

Comment: What do you mean by translate the difference? What difference?

Comment: Thanks. In general when people say origin, do they always mean 0,0?

Comment: It's relative, but generally, yes. This corrected the problem you had?

Comment: So in this case, is origin the 0,0 of the entire window, or the top-left corner of the rectangle?

Comment: Top-left corner, quoting [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5306974/2670792): `"Computer graphics has had the origin in the upper left since the dawn of time, with QuickDraw included. Using the lower left (as in math) is a PostScript/PDF thing. Since Quartz is based on PDF, it uses its coordinates, but that is mostly a unique decision among graphics libraries."`

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but why would I need to translate the rectangle to it's origin before the rotation, if it's already there by definition?

Comment: Sorry for being slow, but could you explain the logic behind what you're suggesting? How exactly does rotation work? Why do I need to translate to the origin, rotate and then translate back? I'd like to understand this throughlly.

Comment: I think I understand, please tell me if something I'm writing is wrong. Steps to rotate a rectangle around it's center: 1- Translate the rectangle so it's new center will be it's previous top-left corner. 2- Rotate the rectangle. 3- Translate the rectangle back to where it was before. Correct?
Also, once again by saying 0,0 - you mean the top left corner of the rectangle, not the screen. Right?

Comment: Yes, I think you understood. Anyways I just finished explaining those steps. See edit.

Comment: Also let me see if I understand another thing: When people say origin, they usually mean 0,0. And 0,0 is always the top-left corner of something, not necesserily the screen. In this case, it's the top-left corner of the rectangle. Correct?

Comment: No, when people (in programming) say **origin**, they mean the origin `(0,0)` of the coordinate system. In your case this is the top-left corner of the screen (forget about the center of the screen). [See this image](http://www.codesampler.com/d3dbook/chapter_03/chapter_03_files/image001.jpg). The center of the rectangle has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Wierd. Then how come I did this to each point of the four, and it worked? `p1.setLocation(p1.getX()-cx,p1.getY()-cy);
  
  p1.setLocation(p1.getX() * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)) - p1.getY() * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90)),
    p1.getX() * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90)) + p1.getY() * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)));
  
  p1.setLocation(p1.getX()+cx,p1.getY()+cy);`

Comment: I subtracted from each point the x and y coordinates of the center of the rectangle, rotated the point, and then added the x and y coordinates of the middile of the rectangle to the point. And it gave me the result I was looking for. How come?

Comment: That code seems to be OK, what's the problem? It follows the steps I described.

Comment: Yes, and it works. But it has nothing to do with 0,0, so how does it work? This is what (I think) it does: 1- Let's name the top-left point of the rectangle point A. In step one, the rectangle moves so point A is now it's center. (point A isn't necesserily 0,0, correct?). 2- Rotate the rectangle. 3- Move the rectangle back to the position where point A is once again the top-left corner of the rectangle. As I said, it seems that this process that I did has nothing to do with the point 0,0. Yet is still works. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are a bit confused, forger about the top-left corner of the Rectangle. In the first step, you are translating the Rectangle points  to the origin (**top-left corner of your screen**). See edit for more. Remember the rotation equations will rotate any point around the origin (**top-left corner of your screen**)

Comment: Added an image with the explanation!

Comment: Okay, I understand now :) I got confused between the x and y coordinates of the center, and the width/2 and height/2 of the rectangle. Thanks for making the effort to help . Really appreciate it :) Cheers

Comment: In your statement to rotate `y1`, you are using the previously rotated `x1`. I think you need another temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

Rotations always happen around 0,0.

In order to rotate around the center of the object you need to move the points so the center of the object is at 0,0; then rotate them; then afterwards move them back again:

So if `cx` and `cy` are your center:

```
    p1.setLocation((p1.getX()-cx) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)) - (p1.getY()-cy) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90))+cx,
            (p1.getX()-cx) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90)) + (p1.getY()-cy) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90))+cy);
```

And do the same for the other points too.

Comment: By 0,0 you mean 0,0 of the entire window, or top-left corner of the rectangle?

Comment: I mean coordinate space.whatever you need to do to move the centre to be at 0 0